# How to programmatically perform "find all references" in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I want to write a visual studio extension to find all references of a certain symbol then perform a "customized Rename".
For example, I have a struct like this

```
struct Foo
{
    int index;
}
```

Now I want to replace the int index with a custom struct like this:

```
struct IndexContainer
{
    int index;
}

struct Foo
{
    IndexContainer indexContainer;
}
```

Then I want to replace all `Foo.index` with `Foo.indexContainer.index`(imagine there are tons of place where `Foo.index` is used).

I want to write a helper tool to automate this work. From what I understand, if I am able to find all the references of this symbol, then I can just iterate all the references and change the text for that reference.

The reason why I cannot simply use Rename is because Rename might change another symbol that is not `Foo.index` and it also can not make static array work(imagine `IndexContainer indexContainer[5]`).

Would anyone tell me if there's a method to invoke "find all references" and grab its result?

Comment: Not sure about the full capabilities but this can be your starting point https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will take a look at it!

Comment: Looks as same as this question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974118/c-sharp-recursively-find-references-in-all-projects-in-solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Recursively Find References in All Projects In Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974118/c-sharp-recursively-find-references-in-all-projects-in-solution)