# Where does Visual Studio is referring the actual NuGet referenced DLL?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nuget

I've added `Autofac` library using `NuGet` and I see it in my references as shown below.

[image]

But when I check the properties [F4] of Autofac by clicking on it, it shows empty property box in Visual Studio.

[image]

Also, I don't see `Autofac` folder under `packages` folder.

[image]

I see only Package reference in `.csproj` file. Then how does it locates the DLL? Where is the actual DLL? I see it's automatically coming inside **BIN**. How does it come?

[image]

**Main Issue**: Locally I'm able to build the solution but same solution fails on TFS build agents. It's unable to find the NuGet reference. So where can I find DLL references? or how to push it to TFS?

Comment: Just as Christian.K and magicandre1981 pointed that the default nuget package repository for `PackageReference`  style package is `%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages`. Now you should use nuget restore to restore those packages on the TFS server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you are using TFS 2015, the NuGet Restore task name should be `NuGet Installer` which under `Package` when you add tasks.

So, if you have installed Nuget in the build machine, then you can use the task directly. 
You can also custom `nuget.exe` for TFS 2015 build -- Just specify the `Path to NuGet.exe`

You can refer to [Mummy's blog- Custom nuget.exe for TFS 2015 build](http://blog.majcica.com/2016/11/02/custom-nuget-exe-for-tfs-2015-build/) for details.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I am creating clear description and testing, will do in few minutes

Comment: But what if, I want to right click the `DLL` and set `Copy Local` to `true` ?

Answer (score 4):

As @magicandre1981 already explained, with `PackageReference` style package referencing (as apposed to `package.config`-style, also see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference) for more background on the differences, in case you didn't know), the packages are not located in a per-solution packages-folder, but in a central one (by default `%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages`). Albeit you can easily change the location using the `NUGET_PACKAGES` environment variable (which also works as a [TFS Build variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch), because they are provided as environment variables to build steps).

Furthermore, inside Visual Studio you see no path, because the actual path to the DLL is determined at build time. You can see part of that path in your `<project-dir>\obj\project.assets.json` file (which is generated during the `restore` target/operation), but the full path you will only see in the MSBuild logs (for example when actually calling the `csc.exe` executable/C# compiler or during `ResolveAssembyReferences`-task).

Note that for .NET Core, i.e. "SDK style" projects, the path is actually shown in properties (as are the actual DLLs in a node underneath the "package" node.

[image: PackageReference in SDK-style projects]

One can only assume that the integration of PackageReference in "old" projects is not fully done yet (if ever).

For comparison a PackageReference in an "old" / non-SDK-style project:

[image: PackageReference in non-SDK-style/old project]

Answer (score 3):

You use the new [Package Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) where the NuGet files get get [stored into a cache](https://blog.nuget.org/20170316/NuGet-now-fully-integrated-into-MSBuild.html):

> Solution-local packages folders are no longer used – Packages are now
>   resolved against the user’s cache at `%userdata%\.nuget`, rather than
>   a solution specific packages folder. This makes PackageReference
>   perform faster and consume less disk space by using a shared folder of
>   packages on your workstation.

Comment: Package Reference already used in *.csproj as shown in question.

Comment: what is your point? I told you what it is and where it stores the data.

Comment: got it. I found it under %userdata%\.nuget.  But why same is not in TFS build server? how do I inform TFS to get nuget packages?

Comment: For future reader's information in case you're still using Windows 7 like me - The path is `%homepath%\.nuget`

Answer (score 1):

Add a `NuGet Restore` task to your build so that the packages are restored.

Comment: I do not see Nuget restore under "Add Tasks" - I am using TFS 2014

Comment: @codetoshare There is no such thing as "TFS 2014". If you mean TFS 2015, there is definitely a NuGet restore task.