# How to see from where comes the Detected Dependencies in a Setup Visual Studio Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, setup-project

I have a **setup project** generating a .MSI file to install a asp.net website on a IIS.
This website have something like 10 project linked to him.

I have a problem when I install the msi. Their is a **conflict between 2 references** (System.Net.Http 4.0.0.0 and System.Net.Http 4.1.1.3).
**In my Detected Dependencies, I have 2 System.Net.Http dll** (2 version) and I have to exclude the 4.0.0.0  to skip the error during the install.
**How can I find what add this dll in my Detected Dependencies**, since I already checked all my project and they are all using the 4.1.1.3.

Maybe another reference need the 4.0.0.0 as dependencie ?
How can I get this global view ?

Comment: It is not the appropriate tool to deploy web apps.  Certainly powerless to deal with the persistent DLL Hell nightmare caused by System.Net.Http.  Google "asp.net deploy to iis" to get ahead.

Comment: Cant change the tool that easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no straightforward way to check the dependencies from a bird's eye view in visual studio atm.

You can find plenty of options [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598129/dependency-graph-of-visual-studio-projects) to check who needs System.Net.Http.

In this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750018/net-dll-references-dependency-checking-utility?rq=1) there is an option to use ildasm for dependency discovery too.